# jQuery: Getting Results from .trigger('click')

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, triggers, click

I am wondering if it is possible to get results from jquery's trigger click function. I am looking to get the url of whatever the click is. I want to click on the button and then capture the url the button goes to and save that into a variable. Is this possible to do? Thanks.

Edit:
I am looking at a button like this:
`<a class="classOne" data-download-url="/somethingone/somethingtwo/somethingthree">Click This</a>`

and when you click on it, you automatically start downloading a file. I am looking to capture the url as it is downloading the file. The url already spits into the console but I want to be able to store that url into a variable. Is this possible?

Comment: what do you mean by `url of button`

Comment: Show us some relevant button code. A <button> typically has no associated url and we can't guess what you are referring to. Take a few minutes to read through [ask]

Comment: You can use `this.dataset.downloadUrl` (see [*MDN: Using data attributes*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Using_data_attributes)). BTW, an A element is for links and anchors, not buttons. If you want a button, use a button element.

Comment: The url entered in the element is a relative url which looks like it goes to a function because the link for the actual file is completely different than what is in the element. Which is why I am trying to capture the url used to download the file rather than just grabbing what is in the element itself.

Oh and the link it made to look like a button which is why I used that terminology. Link and Button can be interchangeable here.

Answer (score 0):

The button doesn't have any url associated with it by default.

if you meant, `on click` function to return the page that you are currently on, you should use:

```
window.location.href
```

Comment: Edited my first post.